# Collada Importer Issues: Missing Bones

Tags: bones, import, collada

Whenever I import Collada/DAE files into Blender, they're always missing bones. However, if I import them into Maya, the bones are clearly there.

Would anyone know what causes this and any solutions there are to it?

Also, a side note, I would use FBX, but Blender seems to lack support for the 7.5 format, so Collada is the only way I can transfer between Maya and Blender.